# How to transfer ether to wallet addresses in an array?

Tags: solidity, remix, address.transfer

```
address[] emp = [address1,address2];
amount = total/emp.length;
for(uint256 i=0;i<employees.length;i++)
{
    wallet = emp[i];
    wallet.transfer(amount);
}
```

So This is the error I get.

TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected address type payable

wallet = emp[i];
^-----^

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `address` needs to be of type `payable` if you want to send Ethers into it.

Looking at the answer here (and its comments): [Member function "transfer" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/63079/member-function-transfer-not-found-or-not-visible-after-argument-dependent-loo/63080#63080) you can convert a regular `address` into `address payable` through `uint160`:

> Converting address to address payable is possible via conversion through uint160

So something like this seems to be at least compile:

```
address a = 0xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c;
uint160 b = uint160(a);
address payable c = address(b);
```

Comment: Just change `address[] emp` to `address payable[] emp`, right?

Comment: I guess that'd work, if the `address1` and `address2` are actually written out and not variables of type `address`.

Comment: No @smarx that wouldn't work I have tried it says "identifier expected but got payable"

Comment: The solution of converting it works perfectly

Comment: @vteja711 Not sure what went wrong, but `address payable[] emp` is certainly legal Solidity syntax and how you declare an array of `address payable`s.

Comment: @smarx tnanks!! I was using the wrong syntax `address[] payable emp`